# Angular 8 - Piping issue when dealing with an http returned observable

Tags: javascript, angular, redirect, error-handling, pipe

I am trying to do a couple things with an http request used to authorize sign in credentials.

First, I am trying to utilize navigateByUrl('/') to redirect the user back to the home page after a successful login/registration.

Second, I want to pass along errors I receive from the server to a previously established empty list of errors.

```
submitForm() {
     this.isSubmitting = true;
     this.errors = new Errors();

     let credentials = this.authForm.value;
     this.userService.attemptAuth(this.authType, credentials)
       .subscribe(
         data => this.router.navigateByUrl('/'),
         err => {
           this.errors = err;
           this.isSubmitting = false;
       }
     );
   }
```

My thought is that I am not supposed to be including both of my arrow functions within the subscribe() method. Should I be piping both of these functions instead? I have a good idea of how to use catchError() within a pipe() call, but am a little unclear on how to perform the url redirect within a pipe().

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: No need to pipe, your implementation should work, also this.isSubmitting = false; need to be also in the data section, since you want to indicate that the submit was done.

Answer (score 0):

**Attempting to answer your original question:** If you wanted to navigate on a pipe, you could do something like this:

```
submitForm() {
    this.isSubmitting = true;
    this.errors = new Errors();

    let credentials = this.authForm.value;
    this.userService.attemptAuth(this.authType, credentials)
        .pipe(
            tap(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/'))
        )
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.isSubmitting = false;
            },
            (error) => {
                this.errors = error;
                this.isSubmitting = false;
            }
        );
}
```

I would discourage this because it simply adds more overhead for something you could already do in the subscribe();